# mysql concurrent and identical transactions trouble

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

OK here's the basic idea of what is happening:

```
begin transaction
some_data=select something from some_table where some_condition;
if some_data does not exists or some_data is outdated
  new_data = insert a_new_entry to some_table
  commit transaction
  return new_data
else
  return some_data
end
```

When multiple processes execute the code above simultaneously(like the client issues a lot of identical requests at a same time), a lot of 'new_data' will be inserted while actually only one is needed.

I think it's a quite typical scenario of concurrency, but still I can't figure out a decent way to avoid it. Things I can think about maybe like having a single worker process to do the select_or_insert job, or maybe set the isolation level to Serializable(unacceptable). But neither is quite satisfactory to me.

PS: The database is mysql, table engine is innodb, and isolation level is repeatable read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initial `SELECT`, use [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

This ensures that the record is locked against other clients reading it until the transaction has been committed (or rolled-back), so they wait on the `SELECT` command and do not continue through to the rest of the logic until the first client has completed its `UPDATE`.

Note that you will need to `ROLLBACK` the transaction in the `else` condition, or else the lock will continue blocking until the connection is dropped.

Comment: Yeah this solve the problem partially. But what if some_data does not exists? What happens if SELECT ... FOR UPDATE actually returns nothing?

Comment: @DeanWinchester: Good point.  One alternative is to use [named locks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html); another would be to define an appropriate `UNIQUE` key then just attempt `INSERT IGNORE` and, if it fails, `SELECT` the old data - no transaction required at all.

Comment: The named lock seems to be a perfect solution to my case. Cool!